# brunch.io not handling compilation errors

Tags: brunch

I created my own brunch configuration to work with coffeescript, jade and stylus.

It works perfectly, except for one major issue. Whenever coffeescript or jade (not had a stylus coding error yet) have issues compiling during `brunch --watch`, I get an error like the following :

```
C:\path\to\node_modules\brunch\lib\fs_utils\pipeline.js:64
          return callback(throwError('Compiling', error));
                 ^
ReferenceError: callback is not defined
    at C:\path\to\node_modules\brunch\lib\fs_utils\pipeline.js:64:18
    at CoffeeScriptCompiler.module.exports.CoffeeScriptCompiler.compile (C:\path\to\node_modules\coffee-script-brunch\lib\index.js:56:16)
    at C:\path\to\node_modules\brunch\lib\fs_utils\pipeline.js:93:31
    at fn (C:\path\to\node_modules\brunch\node_modules\async-waterfall\index.js:19:24)
    at Object._onImmediate (C:\path\to\chromesign\node_modules\brunch\node_modules\async-waterfall\index.js:58:22)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

It looks like the plugin should be passed an error call back, but it isn't happening?

Have I done something wrong in my configuration? The skeleton with all the config is hosted [on GitHub](https://github.com/redders6600/writers-vanilla-brunch). I'd appreciate some input as to whether this is a problem on my side!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you installed brunch from the git master branch when you generated this error. I was unable to reproduce it using v1.7.10. On master (where I *was* able to reproduce it), it's just been fixed with https://github.com/brunch/brunch/commit/68dd9c9b6284c05a4eb01050dba56f80f978e35a. So if you reinstall brunch now, either the latest release (1.7.10) or the edge version from git master, the problem you've reported should go away.

Additionally, you might want to reconsider making brunch a dependency of your skeleton in the package.json. Unless there's a specific reason otherwise, it's better to let it just be installed globally. If you want to clarify to users that your skeleton should only be used with brunch versions >=1.7, you can say so in your readme.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check when I get home :)

Comment: I uninstalled brunch locally and removed it from the `package.json`, then ran `npm install brunch -g`. I still had the error so I used `npm install brunch/brunch -g` which fixed the issue.